# Where should the foreign reside in this scenario

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the relationship to be like a single profile only have one address associated to it. While a single address can be from many profile. Where would I place the foreign key.

Address `address_id, state, town, phone, email`

Profile `username,  profile_pic, date_added, password`

Answer (score 0):

well since you want one to many relation for address table you should add a foreign key ( let's say addr_id ) to profile table.

That way one address row can be used in multiple profiles

Comment: But say am creating a profile where would I get the addr_id.

Comment: depends on which programming lanugage you will use that database. Basic practice says that on a user profile page , frame or any other way you will have to appear your data , it will be a combo box with all available adrresses to select

Comment: I want the other way round... That is I want the user to provide the address information by themselve

Comment: In that case , user will provide the address himself . The you must do a SQL query on the address table to see if there is a match, if yes then return the address_id of the match as foreign key to profile table. If no , create a new entry in address table and retreive the new adrress_id as foreign key to profile table. Hope that helps

Comment: Yh...ok... Then query please. How would it be.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/:

"The customers table is called parent table or referenced table, and the orders table is known as child table or referencing table.

A foreign key can be a column or a set of columns. The columns in the child table often refer to the primary key columns in the parent table."

Looks like you want the foreign key on the user table.

Hope this helps!